# Speed of CD/DVD unit in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: hardware, dvd

I have intalled Ubuntu 12.04 on my Acer laptop and the problem with the unit of CD/DVD is that it do not reduce the speed of reproduction. In other vertions of Ubuntu this probles was solved with "reduce the speed of the disks when is posible" (or, at least, this option solved the problem for me)but in this vesrsion it is not possible. When I reproduce a DVD picture, the noise of the unit isself and the vibration donẗ allow to hear the sound of the picture. I have tried with VLC reproducer but this is not a solution beause even when I reduce the "speed of reproduction" in the tools of VLC, the sound is distorted but the speed remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
hdparm -E 4 /dev/cdrom1
```

where `/dev/cdrom1` is your cd/dvd device (may be different) and `4` is the actual speed (in this example 4x).

Answer (score 0):

For handling speed of optical drive use eject

```
eject -x <speed_number>
```

for eg     `eject -x 4` for 4x speed
edit the number 4 for your own speed
By definitoin: Eject  allows  removable  media (typically a CD-ROM,
       floppy disk, tape, or JAZ or ZIP disk) to be ejected
       under software control. The command can also control
       some multi-disc CD-ROM changers, the auto-eject fea‐
       ture  supported  by some devices, and close the disc
       tray of some CD-ROM drives.

Cheers